# Date subtraction from empty cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have no clue how to do this or where to start. I don't even know how to Google the question correctly.

I have two dates

```
08/21/2011 - 04/22/19 = 2800 Days
```

What I have in  Excel `=O518-P518` gives `2800` days in a parallel cell.

My dilemma is thus:

```
09/19/2019 - (EMPTY CELL) = -40805
```

I put in `=Today()` to fix the issue temporarily. However, I need to write a formula that will do `=Today()` unless a date is entered into a corresponding cell to add up to the amount of days employed? Or if not possible. Is it a way to have it be `0` until a date is entered to subtract from?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
=O518 - If(P518="", TODAY(), P518)
```

Or:

```
=0518 - If(P518="", O518, P518)
```

So it always returns 0 unless there is something in `P518`

Alternatively you could test the whole thing:

```
=if(0518 - P518 < 0, 0, 0518 - P518)
```

Where if it returns a number less than 0 it will output 0.